# sync transactions in each node Blockchain python

Tags: python, transactions, synchronization, blockchain

I am writing a simple blockchain using python, currently have some trouble syncing my transactions pools which are holding transactions! I wrote a method that gets the other nodes awaiting transactions and adds them to the `self.transactions`
then when I mine a new block this pool would be empty. I know there must be some bugs but I want to know how to handle confirmations.

```
def syn(self):
         network=self.nodes
         for node in network:
                otherts = requests.get(f'http://{node}/tspool')
                response= otherts.json()
         self.transactions+=response
```

note: the response has other nodes awaiting transaction